# Array of procs or array of lambdas

Tags: ruby, lambda

Is there a way to create an array of lambdas or an array of procs in ruby? I've been able to define arrays of each, but I have not been able to figure out the syntax for calling the lambdas/procs in the array.

As a foolish made-up example, consider this:

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
b = [2, 3, 5, 7, 10]

c = [
  Proc.new { |x| a.include? x },
  Proc.new { |x| true },
  Proc.new { |x| b.include? x }
]

def things_checker(element, checks)
  z = 0
  checks.each do |check|
    p z
    break unless check(element)
    z = z + 1
  end
end

things_checker(3, c)
```

I can't figure out a way to get `check(element)` to not be a syntax error.

Comment: How would you call a lamba/proc outside an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to call a `proc` in Ruby. All those will work:

```
break unless check.call(element)
break unless check.(element)
break unless check[element]
```

and even:

```
break unless check === element
```

IMHO, in the example you provided, the latter is mostly semantically correct. It works because triple-equal, also known as case-equal, is invented to be used in `case` statements to check the result of call on the argument for being truthy.

Answer (score 3):

You use `call` to execute a proc/lambda:

```
def things_checker(element, checks)
  z = 0
  checks.each do |check|
    p z
    break unless check.call(element)
    z = z + 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

lambda / proc can be called with `#[]` and `#call`

```
a = Proc.new { |x| x > 10 }
a[11] # => true
a.call(9) # => false
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need an extra `.`

```
break unless check.(element)
```

test run:

```
$ ruby
a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
b = [2, 3, 5, 7, 10]

c = [
  Proc.new { |x| a.include? x },
  Proc.new { |x| true },
  Proc.new { |x| b.include? x }
]

def things_checker(element, checks)
  z = 0
  checks.each do |check|
    p z
    break unless check.(element)
    z = z + 1
  end
end

things_checker(3, c)
```

---

```
0
1
2
```